# Shell Scripting: What does -z mean in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, sh

I have a code which does something like this:

```
if [ -z "$SOME_VARIABLE" ]; then
    echo "something something 1"
else
    echo "something something 2"
fi
```

I have no clue what "-z" is doing here. Can someone explain please?

Comment: why there is -1 here? is something wrong in the question?

Comment: Have you read *any* documentation for your shell?

Comment: So you assumed that I didn't read the document, that's why u marked it -1?

Comment: Yes, because lack of research is *exactly* what a downvote indicates on a question, and it takes very little effort to find out what `-z` means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -z string: True if string is empty.

http://linuxcommand.org/wss0090.php

Answer (score 1):

`[` is a command like any other, just with an unusual name. You can check the `[` man page to see what its flags mean.

```
$ man [

<snip>

       -n STRING
              the length of STRING is nonzero

       STRING equivalent to -n STRING

       -z STRING
              the length of STRING is zero
```